# Parsing HTML data with BeautifulSoup - cannot extract the 'href' out in one string

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse out the html to get the - 'href' link;
My code is parsing the 'href link' into separate string, but I'm hoping to get a complete string.

Here is my code:

```
data = requests.get("https://www.chewy.com/b/food_c332_p2", 
                    auth = ('user', 'pass'), 
                    headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent})

with open("dogfoodpage/dg2.html","w+") as f:
    f.write(data.text)

with open("dogfoodpage/dg2.html") as f:
    page = f.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page,"html.parser")
     
test = soup.find('a',class_= "kib-product-title")

productlink = []

for items in test:
   for link in items.get("href"):
       productlink.append(link)
```

Here is my output:

[image: output of my code]

Here is the html structure for test:

[image: html for test]

Comment: `"".join(productlink)` ?

Comment: Please, post the code and the output as text, not image

Comment: @Alec_djinn I did post the code too along with the image. But I will make it clear.

Comment: As it is, we can't reproduce the error since the source of `"dogfoodpage/dg2.html"` is missing. Also, in line 3, `'html.parser` has a hanging `'`. Please, provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @alec_djinn gotcha! just added it in. thanks!

Comment: Still missing `user_agent`. I can't run your code and reproduce the error yet. Also, specify the imports, where is `requests` coming from?

Answer (score 0):

```
productlink = []
for items in test:
    for link in items.find_all('a', class_="kib-product-title"):
        productlink.append(link.get('href'))
```

This should work. `find` method returns a single `href` as a string and while looping over the string you are getting `URL` as a list divided into characters. `find_all` method will get all the links and we can iterate over it to get the links.

Comment: I'd tried this code, but the output is a blank list.